# Raphael js image rendering in VML is slow

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, raphael, vml

I am using Raphaeljs (http://raphaeljs.com/) to render images having text. The rendering of images on IE9 and Firefox are quite fast with SVG but in IE8 and 7 where VML is used, there is a delay before the contents of the image appear on the paper.

In IE8 and 7 it gives an impression that the page is blank and after waiting a bit more (sometimes 3-4 seconds) the image contents appear.

Is there anything I can do to get a callback when the image is completely rendered, by modifying the Raphael code or otherwise? I can then use this callback to show/hide a spinner on the holder div.

I have tried to put console output statements after some of the Raphael functions in the VML section to see if any particular function when finished, can indicate the completion of the rendering. But the rendering of the image takes place even after all of them are finished running.

Following is the outline of the code I am using:

```
loadimg = new Image();
imgHolder = paper.image("", -1, -1, 1, 1 );
loadimg.onload = function(imgHolder, xpos, ypos, width, height) {
    return function() {
        imgHolder.attr({ x: xpos, y: ypos, width: width, height: height });
        imgHolder.attr( { src: this.src } );
    }
} ( imgHolder, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight );
loadimg.src = pageurl;
```